# Database cleanup after Junit tests

Tags: java, database, unit-testing, junit

I have to test some Thrift services using Junit. When I run my tests as a Thrift client, the services modify the server database. I am unable to find a good solution which can clean up the database after each test is run.
Cleanup is important especially because the IDs need to be unique which are currently read form an XML file. Now, I have to manually change the IDs after running tests, so that the next set of tests can run without throwing primary key violation in the database. If I can cleanup the database after each test run, then the problem is completely resolved, else I will have to think about other solutions like generating random IDs and using them wherever IDs are required.

Edit: I would like to emphasize that I am testing a service, which is writing to database, I don't have direct access to the database. But since, the service is ours, I can modify the service to provide any cleanup method if required.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Unless you as testing specific database actions (verifying you can query or update the database for example) your JUnits shouldn't be writing to a real database.  Instead you should mock the database classes.  This way you don't actually have to connect and modify the database and therefor no cleanup is needed.

You can mock your classes a couple of different ways.  You can use a library such as [JMock](http://www.jmock.org/) which will do all the execution and validation work for you.  My personal favorite way to do this is with Dependency Injection.  This way I can create mock classes that implement my repository interfaces (you are using interfaces for your data access layer right?  ;-)) and I implement only the needed methods with known actions/return values.

```
//Example repository interface.
public interface StudentRepository
{
   public List<Student> getAllStudents();
}

//Example mock database class.
public class MockStudentRepository implements StudentRepository
{
   //This method creates fake but known data.
   public List<Student> getAllStudents()
   {
      List<Student> studentList =  new ArrayList<Student>();
      studentList.add(new Student(...));
      studentList.add(new Student(...));
      studentList.add(new Student(...));

      return studentList;
   }
}

//Example method to test.
public int computeAverageAge(StudentRepository aRepository)
{
   List<Student> students = aRepository.GetAllStudents();
   int totalAge = 0;
   for(Student student : students)
   {
      totalAge += student.getAge();
   }

   return totalAge/students.size();
}

//Example test method.
public void testComputeAverageAge()
{
   int expectedAverage = 25; //What the expected answer of your result set is
   int actualAverage = computeAverageAge(new MockStudentRepository());

   AssertEquals(expectedAverage, actualAverage);
}
```

Comment: "`Unless you as testing specific database actions (verifying you can query or update the database for example) your JUnits shouldn't be writing to a real database.`" There's not a universal agreement about this. In one camp, we have those people who believe that the database should be mocked and in the other hand we have those that believe that all database tests should be performed against a real database, ideally one that matches the production database.

Comment: Sorry, I am a little new to all this stuff, was coding in flex for some time. Could you please elaborate on what I am required to do. I am not sure what you mean by mock classes and not modifying the database. Typically , the tests I run create new Customer and use that customer to create orders and other things. Where would all this data go if not to a database?

Comment: When you need to retrieve data you create a class and implement the method you need returning the data that you need.  If you need to save data you create a class and implement the save (whatever it is called) method.  This method can just store the data in instance variable(s). If you need to save and retrieve then those methods just need to read and write from the same instance variable(s).

Answer (score 20):

If you are using Spring, everything you need is the @DirtiesContext annotation on your test class.

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration("/test-context.xml")
@DirtiesContext(classMode = ClassMode.AFTER_EACH_TEST_METHOD)
public class MyServiceTest {
   ....
}
```

Comment: DirtiesContext is about recreation of Spring context - it's time-consuming operation, so it is not good way

Comment: That's not a good solution for any real project. It will boot up spring boot app for every test. After few test classes it will take minutes to finish and will slow down development by a lot. You want your tests quick so you can run them as often as possible to avoid breaking code.

Answer (score 5):

How about using something like [DBUnit](http://dbunit.sourceforge.net/)?

Answer (score 4):

Spring's unit testing framework has extensive capabilities for dealing with JDBC. The general approach is that the unit tests runs in a transaction, and (outside of your test) the transaction is rolled back once the test is complete.

This has the advantage of being able to use your database and its schema, but without making any direct changes to the data. Of course, if you actually perform a commit inside your test, then all bets are off!

For more reading, look at [Spring's documentation](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/testing.html#integration-testing-support-jdbc) on integration testing with JDBC.

Answer (score 4):

When writing JUnit tests, you can override two specific methods: setUp() and tearDown(). In setUp(), you can set everything thats necessary in order to test your code so you dont have to set things up in each specific test case. tearDown() is called after all the test cases run.

If possible, you could set it up so you can open your database in the setUp() method and then have it clear everything  from the tests and close it in the tearDown() method. This is how we have done all testing when we have a database.

Heres an example:

```
@Override
protected void setUp() throws Exception {
    super.setUp();
    db = new WolfToursDbAdapter(mContext);
    db.open();

    //Set up other required state and data
}

@Override
protected void tearDown() throws Exception {
    super.tearDown();
    db.dropTables();
    db.close();
    db = null;
}

//Methods to run all the tests
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you have access to the database: Another option is to create a backup of the database just before the tests and restore from that backup after the tests. This can be automated.

Comment: yes, I have access to the database and that is what I am also planning to do after talking to a couple of collegues. thanks John.

Comment: @Manfred could you tell me how?

Comment: @AhmedHussein In general database servers have command line clients that allow creating a backup of a db or restore a db from backup. You could add these steps to the script that automatically executes your tests. Before the tests start, you could drop the existing database and restore a database with the content you need for testing. That way your tests will always have a well defined set of data to start with. Some issue may exist if your data includes data along a time axis. In this and possibly other cases you may need additional steps to prepare the database for the test suite.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Spring + Junit 4.x then you don't need to insert anything in DB. 
Look at 
[AbstractTransactionalJUnit4SpringContextTests](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/api/org/springframework/test/context/junit4/AbstractTransactionalJUnit4SpringContextTests.html) class.

Also check out the Spring documentation for JUnit support.

Answer (score 1):

It's a bit draconian, but I usually aim to wipe out the database (or just the tables I'm interested in) before every test method execution.  This doesn't tend to work as I move into more integration-type tests of course.

In cases where I have no control over the database, say I want to verify the correct number of rows were created after a given call, then the test will count the number of rows before and after the tested call, and make sure the difference is correct.  In other words, take into account the existing data, then see how the tested code changed things, without assuming anything about the existing data.  It can be a bit of work to set up, but let's me test against a more "live" system.

In your case, are the specific IDs important?   Could you generate the IDs on the fly, perhaps randomly, verify they're not already in use, then proceed?

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Brainimus if you're trying to test against data you have pulled from a database. If you're looking to test modifications made to the database, another solution would be to mock the database itself. There are multiple implementations of in-memory databases that you can use to create a temporary database (for instance during JUnit's `setUp()`) and then remove  the entire database from memory (during `tearDown()`). As long as you're not using an vendor-specific SQL, then this is a good way to test modifying a database without touching your real production one.

Some good Java databases that offer in memory support are [Apache Derby](http://db.apache.org/derby/), [Java DB](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javadb/overview/index.html) (but it is really Oracle's flavor of Apache Derby again), [HyperSQL](http://www.hsqldb.org/) (better known as HSQLDB) and [H2 Database Engine](http://www.h2database.com/html/main.html). I have personally used HSQLDB to create in-memory mock databases for testing and it worked great, but I'm sure the others would offer similar results.